# How can I do math on fields?

Tags: forms

I am trying to learn the principals required to make a Drupal 7 math/calculator module that simply takes user's inputs and does some math on them and then displays the results on the same page without a page refresh.

Comment: I think that "without a page refresh" will automatically include JavaScript, as doron said.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal modules are basically PHP code, and because PHP is on the server side, you cannot do mathematical actions upon user's input without submitting your data to the server(Which will refresh your page).

The only solution to do what you want is to add some Javasciprt to do it for you.

Here is a tutorial explaining how to add JS to Drupal

https://www.drupal.org/node/756722

Comment: Just note that JavaScript is somewhat bad at math when decimals are present.

Comment: This isn't really accurate.  Drupal has an [Ajax Framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) built in, so you could easily make up a UI based on the Form API, and wire up AJAX callbacks to it for getting/displaying results w/o a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The options suggested above are prefect, but there is no use of creating a calculator widget that does a full round trip to get the answer.

So i would recommend to use only javascript to get this done. The following code will help you to parse Integer(parseInt) and Decimal(parseFloat) values.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var result = parseFloat("10.3333") + parseFloat("10.3333");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks